# Equation of a plane passing through a point

Tags: calculus, 3d

Write an equation of the plane with normal vector n=<-6, 9, -8> passing through the point (-1, 3, 4) in scalar form.  The equation should equal 2.

I just learned this topic and I am having trouble starting this question.

I tried plugging the point into the equation.

-6(-1) + 9(3) - 8(4) = 1

I'm not sure what else to do. Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ a very general equation of a plane looks like this: $$A(x - x_0) + B(y-y_0) + C(z-z_0) = 0$$ where $ \vec{n} = \langle A,B,C \rangle$ is the normal vector and $(x_0 , y_0 , z_0)$ is a point on the plane.